# contnet of post is missing when share a post on facebook page itself

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, share, facebook-sharer

I have a website, where i share some content to the Facebook through app and it works well ,there is two situation first when we post content manually on Facebook  page, you can share it again with all data. but in second case when you share data through code,anyone can share the content again on Facebook page but the description of post is missing.

Comment: Given that it's unlikely all of Facebook is broken and no one noticed, the problem is likely to be in your page/code. Hard for us to fix it without an example.

Comment: thanks for replying..what kind of example you need...snapshots or code
pls help.

Comment: problem is solved.i just add a og:type meta tag and send description value in code..thanks for help.